# Find optimal solution for this system of quadratic equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

I would like to find an optimal (e.g. like in a least square manner) solution for the following system of equations (noisy distance measurements between 4 points):

$ (\color{green}{x_1}-x_2)^2+(\color{green}{y_1-y_2})^2=(\color{green}{d_{1,2}})^2$

$ (\color{green}{x_1}-x_3)^2+(\color{green}{y_1}-y_3)^2=(\color{green}{d_{1,3}})^2$

$ (\color{green}{x_1}-x_4)^2+(\color{green}{y_1}-y_4)^2=(\color{green}{d_{1,4}})^2$

$ (x_2-x_3)^2+(\color{green}{y_2}-y_3)^2=(\color{green}{d_{2,3}})^2$

$ (x_2-x_4)^2+(\color{green}{y_2}-y_4)^2=(\color{green}{d_{2,4}})^2$

$ (x_3-x_4)^2+(y_3-y_3)^2=(\color{green}{d_{3,4}})^2$

Let's assume that the green are the known ones (with $x_1, y_1, y_2 = 0$) and the black are the unknown ones. If there is no single solution (due to noise in the measurements), how should I approach the problem? I also reckon that setting $x_1,y_1,y_2 = 0$ is not enough since the system solution could still be a reflection about the segment formed by these two points, but I do not mind accepting any of the two solutions.

Lastly, let me mention that my system involves in fact $20$ points (i.e. $190$ equations with $37$ unknowns)

Comment: First of all you can find two $(x_2,y_2)$ from the very first equation ( intersection of a line and a circle of radius $d_{1,2}$. Then for each $(x_2,y_2)$ we can find one $(x_3,y_3)$ and $(x_4,y_4)$ from intersection of two circles (from eq: 2 ; 4 and eq:3;5). At last from equation 6, we can filter out one $(x_3,y_3)$ and one $(x_4,y_4)$.

Comment: But given that there is some noise in all measured distances, to solve the first eq for X2 and use that at the next calculations, assumes that there is no noise in the measured distance of the first eq (namely d1,2). Which is not true. Ideally, an optimization could fine tune d1,2 too.

Comment: If there is some noise, then $x_2$ can be thought very little line segments on $X$ axis centered one around $d_{1,2}$ and other around $-d_{1,2}$.

Comment: I am terribly sorry ! I misread the equations (I am almost blind). I delete my answer and I shall try ro rework the problem (which is more difficult as long as no estimates).